# Assigning complex values in gsl

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, complex-numbers, gsl

I am trying to use GSL for `complex numbers`, `complex vectors` and `complex matrices` in my project. I am using VS2010 and I added the address of library in **Configuration Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories**.  But I have a stupid problem. As far as I understood, I can not use `=` to assign two `gsl_complex`, `gsl_vector_complex` or `gsl_matrix_complex` to each other.

For vectors I have to use `gsl_vector_complex_set` and for matrices `gsl_matrix_complex_set`. But for gsl_complex, I only found  **GSL_SET_COMPLEX** in which I should give the real and imaginary parts seperatly as 2 arguments:

```
GSL_SET_COMPLEX (zp, real, imaginary)
```

In my code I have such function:

```
gsl_complex cmx, cmx2;
void vector_complex_exp(gsl_vector_complex *v)
{
    for (i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        gsl_vector_complex_set(v, i, gsl_complex_exp(gsl_vector_complex_get(v, i)));
    }
}
```

Using this, I get following errors:

> error LNK1120: 2 Unresolved external references.
>
> error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_hypot".
>
> error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".
>
> error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".

I didn't understand the reason behind these errors. But I rewrite my code like this:

```
void vector_complex_exp(gsl_vector_complex *v)
{
    for (i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        cmx = gsl_vector_complex_get(v, i);
        //cmx2 = gsl_complex_exp(cmx);
        gsl_vector_complex_set(v, i, cmx2);
    }
}
```

Here when the second line in for is commented, there's no error. But when I uncomment it I get the following:

> error LNK1120: 2 non-resolved external references.
>
> error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".
>
> error LNK2019: Reference to non-resolved external symbol "_hypot" in function "_gsl_complex_div".
>
> error LNK2019: Reference to non-resolved external symbol "_log1p" in function "_gsl_complex_logabs".

I don't have any `_gsl_complex_div` or `_gsl_complex_logabs` function in my code. So I am pretty sure that the problem is with assignment here. But I can not use GSL_SET_COMPLEX here too.

Can someone help me with this? Is there really no way to assign a value to gsl_complex directly?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you published all your code here, therefore, I immediately used this code from [the lowest of the examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/eigen.html?highlight=gsl_vector_complex_get#examples) of the GSL.  I made some small changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_eigen.h>

int main(void)
{
double data[] = { -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -8.0, 4.0, -2.0, 1.0,
    27.0, 9.0, 3.0, 1.0,
    64.0, 16.0, 4.0, 1.0 };

gsl_matrix_view m
    = gsl_matrix_view_array(data, 4, 4);

gsl_vector_complex *eval = gsl_vector_complex_alloc(4);
gsl_matrix_complex *evec = gsl_matrix_complex_alloc(4, 4);

gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_workspace * w = gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_alloc(4);

gsl_eigen_nonsymmv(&m.matrix, eval, evec, w);

gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_free(w);

gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_sort(eval, evec, GSL_EIGEN_SORT_ABS_DESC);

{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        gsl_complex eval_i
            = gsl_vector_complex_get(eval, i);
        gsl_vector_complex_view evec_i
            = gsl_matrix_complex_column(evec, i);

        printf("\n eigenvalue = %g + %gi\n",
            GSL_REAL(eval_i), GSL_IMAG(eval_i));
        printf(" eigenvector = \n");
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            gsl_complex z =
                gsl_vector_complex_get(&evec_i.vector, j);
            printf("        %g + %gi\n", GSL_REAL(z), GSL_IMAG(z));
        }
    }
}

gsl_vector_complex_free(eval);
gsl_matrix_complex_free(evec);

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

[Output of this code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScPka.png)
(from the red arrow and below there is a mismatch with the expected output in the GSL example)
To get my output, you need to IDE (I use Visual Studio 2015):

1. into "your_application" Property pages -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> (right pane)in line **Executable Directories** type: **C:\Users\ *...(your GSL build directory path)...* \gsl\Release;$(ExecutablePath)**
2. ibid. in line **Include Directories** type: **C:\Users\ *...(your GSL build directory path)...* \gsl;$(IncludePath)**
3. ibid. in line **Library Directories** type: **C:\Users\ *...(your GSL build directory path)...* \gsl\Release;$(LibraryPath)**
4. Below, in the left pane, select C/C++ -> Peprocessor -> (right pane) in line **Preprocessor Defenition** type: **WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;GSL_DLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)** (I use Debug mode, created empty console application). Save settings (press "Apply" and "OK" buttons)
5. Copy and put into Debug directories of your application project folder **gsl.dll** and **gslcblas.dll** from **C:\Users\ *...(your GSL build directory path)...* \gsl\Release** directory
6. Buld your application and run it
7. **NOTE!:** In the beginning it is best to rebuild GSL with your compiler for the target application - then the work will be guaranteed.

Good luck!